# parse string from an api to html

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have api call that sets a collection of 10 objects into a state array. Below is an example of that code:

```
class Example extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            quiz_data: [],

            quiz_answers:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('api call here')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ 'quiz_data': response.data });
            })
    }
```

Then, I map over that state array like so:

```
this.quizData = this.state.quiz_data.map((item, id) => {
                return (
                    <div key={id}>
                        <h3 className='quiz-question'>{item.Title}</h3>
                        <p>{item.Question}</p>
                    </div>
                )
})
```

My question/problem is, that the item.question is returned as a string in the array, and comes out that way.

So i end up with example text with code inside instead of just

**example text**

.

How do i get it to return as html instead of a string?

Comment: What does console.log(item.Question) yield?

Comment: example data question?<br /><br />second example data question?

Comment: I see. And the <br /> is displayed as a text? Did you see this value in the console of your dev tools?

Comment: correct. its not parsing the html tags. I had never run across this before. I guess i just assumed that it would. So how do i convert it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you try setting the html dangerously read [here](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

```
this.quizData = this.state.quiz_data.map((item, id) => {
                return (
                    <div key={id}>
                        <h3 className='quiz-question'>{item.Title}</h3>
                       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:item.Question}} /> 
                    </div>
                )
})
```